# Querying for distinct data in XML Column in SqlServer 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have some xml data stored in an XML Column in a table in sql server 2005.

Record1 would have data for that column would look like this:

```
<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">
  <Things>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Monkey</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Lion</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Shoe</Name>
    </Thing>
  </Things>
</ArrayOfThings>
```

Record 2 might have data like this for that column

```
<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">
  <Things>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Monkey</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Elephant</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Hammer</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Bucket</Name>
    </Thing>
  </Things>
</ArrayOfThings>
```

Can anyone help me with what the syntax would look like to select distinct things from this table.

The results returned would look like this:
Monkey
Lion
Shoe
Elephant
Hammer
Bucket

obviously this is not production data :)

Setup script:

```
CREATE TABLE [SomeSchema].[MyTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ThingData] [xml] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Party] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [SomeSchema].[MyTable]
           ([ThingData])
     VALUES
           ( 
'<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">
  <Things>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Monkey</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Lion</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Shoe</Name>
    </Thing>
  </Things>
</ArrayOfThings>
')
GO

INSERT INTO [SomeSchema].[MyTable]
           ([ThingData])
     VALUES
           (
'<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">
  <Things>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Monkey</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Elephant</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Hammer</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Bucket</Name>
    </Thing>
  </Things>
</ArrayOfThings>
')
GO
```

And the select would go against the column in the table

Comment: Do you want them in one line?

Comment: No, just those values in the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create table #t1(id int not null identity(1,1),ThingData xml)`

`insert #t1(ThingData) values (
'<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">  <Things>    <Thing>        <Name>Monkey</Name>    </Thing>    <Thing>        <Name>Lion</Name>    </Thing>    <Thing>        <Name>Shoe</Name>    </Thing>  </Things></ArrayOfThings>')`

`insert #t1(ThingData) values (
 '<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">  <Things>    <Thing>        <Name>Monkey</Name>    </Thing>    <Thing>        <Name>Elephant</Name>    </Thing>    <Thing>        <Name>Hammer</Name>    </Thing>    <Thing>        <Name>Bucket</Name>    </Thing>  </Things></ArrayOfThings>')`

`;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany' AS ns)
select DISTINCT Array.Things.value('(ns:Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from #t1
 cross apply #t1.[ThingData].nodes('/ns:ArrayOfThings/ns:Things/ns:Thing') as Array(Things)`

Comment: I used a temporary table here, but I hope you get the idea. Good artists copy, great artists steal.

Answer (score 1):

You could also easily use the SQL Server 2005 built-in XQuery language instead of the clunky of OPENXML stuff and achieve the same result very easily:

```
DECLARE @input XML 
SET @input = '<ArrayOfThings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany">
  <Things>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Monkey</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Elephant</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Hammer</Name>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Name>Bucket</Name>
    </Thing>
  </Things>
</ArrayOfThings>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany' AS ns)
SELECT
    DISTINCT Array.Things.value('(ns:Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/ns:ArrayOfThings/ns:Things/ns:Thing') AS Array(Things)
```

You basically create a "pseudo-table" called `Array.Things` that contains one "row" for each entry of that specified type - here a `<Thing>` inside the structure given.

Then you can reach into those "rows" and grab out the individual elements, here the `<Name>` value, and you can select those and work with them.

Comment: @vgv8: they're quite obviously **NOT** in the input XML as defined and shown by the OP (as record #2).... if they're not there, they can't be retrieved.... as simple as that.....

Comment: I converted this to use the table in my example SELECT @input = thingdata from [System].[mytable]; and it only returns data from the first record and doesn't consider the data in following rows.

Answer (score 0):

If to use

> Setup script:
>   CREATE TABLE [SomeSchema].[MyTable]( ....

from question, then:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany' AS ns) 
select DISTINCT Array.Things.value('(ns:Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') Name 
FROM    [SomeSchema].[MyTable] MT
CROSS APPLY 
MT.ThingData.nodes('/ns:ArrayOfThings/ns:Things/ns:Thing') 
AS Array(Things)
```